# Dúvida métodos Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Saudações

Estou com uma dúvida sobre métodos em javascript.
Alguém pode me dizer se isso é um método e que tipo de método é esse.

```
nomeMetodo : function (){
  //code
}
```

no casso não seria assim...

```
function nomeMetodo () {
  //code
}
```

Comment: É um método sim. Com objetos literais, conseguimos invocar funções da maneira como você exemplificou. Dê uma lida sobre objetos.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos#Definindo_m%C3%A9todos

Comment: O primeiro é um **Método**, você o utiliza dentro de um objeto, no caso aí `nomeMetodo` seria uma propriedade do objeto cujo seu valor é uma função. O segundo é uma **Função** normal.

Answer (score 0):

As duas formas estão corretas.

O javascript trabalha com o conceito de função anônima, se chama anônima justamente porque você não precisa definir um nome a ela, como abaixo.

`function (){
  //code
}`

Essa função anônima geralmente vai ser usada quando você precisa atribuir a função a uma variável

`var nomeMetodo = function (){
  //code
}`

ou criar uma função em um objeto:

`var x = {
    a: 2,
    nomeMetodo: function() {
        return this.a;
    }
}`

Nesse caso se você chamar x.nomeMetodo() ele vai retornar o valor de a

Tudo vai depender de como você usa a sua função... se quiser saber um pouco mais, recomendo começar pela [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: Devo adicionar a sua resposta que existe uma diferença em declarar uma função, e atribuir uma função a uma variável. Vide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname